# How can i show .dng image file format in html

Tags: javascript, html

How can I show .dng file format in HTML

I need to show the .dng file on my HTML image view

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not support that format. You need to convert it to a format that they do support.

You could do that with client-side JavaScript (if you found or wrote a conversion library) but it would probably be easier to do that on your server, at build time, or manually.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it with [npm:extractd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extractd) (or some another image converter tool, depending on your server language) into a jpg on the server side.

While conversion on client side is theoretically possible, there may be no library for that (you could try to find one though)

Conversion is REQUIRED, as HTML browsers have a limited subset od supported image formats.